# How can one best clarify the different senses of “compare”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests, word-usage

I have long felt that the taboo on comparing anyone to Hitler and many similar inhibitions were based on a confusion between “compare” in the senses of “liken to” and in the sense of “compare and contrast”, and [this answer on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92305/60831) gave me the idea of asking here how to express this effectively.

The formulations that occur to me are

- “**liken A to B**” for “*suggest that A is (very) similar to B*” (sometimes risky)
- “**compare and contrast A and B**” for “*consider various attributes of A and B and evaluate how similar they are in each such attribute*” (usually useful),

but the latter seems a wee bit long-winded. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compare) suggests “**compare A to B**” and “**compare A with B**” respectively, but I am not convinced that that distinction is widely recognised. There is perhaps also the sense of using one feature of something well known to make a description more effective ([“*thou art more lovely and more temperate*”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_18)), but that seems more a matter of rhetoric than of a pitfall in thinking.

Can anyone suggest preferably terse and widely recognised ways of expressing these senses unambiguously, and of pointing out that someone is confusing them?

Comment: *Compare* seems to say that the two things being compared have a common set of attributes but the values of those attributes may be different: the *height*  of one person compared to the *height* of another.  *Contrast* implies looking at attributes that are not common: A has a moustache but B doesn’t.

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand the issue with regard to Hitler.

Comment: @HotLicks: Can you explain? I think likening to Hitler is dodgy, but analysing differences and similarities often desirable or essential.

Comment: @Jim: surely we also _contrast_ a tall and a short person? _Compare and contrast_ is (or was) of course a common formulation in examination questions.

Comment: The problem is that in *any* way comparing a person to Hitler is deemed pejorative.  I mean, even if you say "He's at the opposite extreme from Hitler" that's damning with faint praise.

Comment: Hitler is, for the modern, the definition of evil.  Invoking his name is a worthless self serving exercise.  As indicated above, it is invariably a pejorative.  The taboo you 
mention has nothing to do with confusion.  You should have used another example to ask
the question.

Comment: @PJTraill - it all depends on how you frame it.  You can compare their height (they both have a height) - one is taller than the other.  Or you can dispense with the common attribute and say one is tall while the other is short. I.e., one has the *tall* attribute while the other doesn’t.

Comment: The taboo with comparisons and analogies to Hitler or to the Nazi party has more to do with the fact that, increasingly over time, people will fall back on making them in a manner that belittles just how vile they were.  For example, the colloquialism "grammar Nazi": no one using the term is suggesting that people who correct others' grammar want to round up people with poor grammar into concentration camps for execution (I hope); it's just a cheap rhetorical tactic to directly or indirectly liken something to the third Reich and, in so doing, make it the "wrong" side of any discussion.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I frequently suggest EXACTLY that... but I don't truly believe it. The grammar Nazi's are too busy editing and re-editing their manifesto. Based on the incoherent snippets they keep posting, we're safe for a few more decades.

Comment: I think you mean "Nazis"; "Nazi's" is the possessive form.  In this comment I am clearly not blindly falling for the devious and subtle trap which you have so neatly prepared.  Now please hold on as I work on my "Grammatik macht Frei" ironwork for the front gate to a new community development upon which I'm currently working.

Answer (score 1):

I like to distinguish between *comparing* and *equating.*

In an argument, unfortunately, you cannot logically convince someone not to use a dishonest tactic against you. If someone wants to dismiss your line of reasoning because they do not like a comparison, and they fail to understand the difference between a comparison you gave to illustrate a point, vs a comparison you made to try and logically assert your point (ie an actual "argument by analogy" fallacy) it's unlikely that you'll convince them to behave otherwise.

When I say "rocks, bananas, and the service of prostitutes can all be purchased for money" I am certainly comparing one aspect of all of those things, and yet we all agree these things are very different. Does that mean my sentence is inaccurate? Of course not. It means that I am *comparing* them, but not *equating* them.